# Schur test and it's relation to representation theory

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, representation-theory

I was told by analyst who doesn't know about such things that [Schur's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_test) relating to boundedness of integral operators is somehow a version of [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma) on irreducible representations, the group being $\mathbb R$. The two statements look very different to me (although there seem to be many things named after Schur and I have little experience in rep theory). Does anyone know the details of this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that there are many things named after I. Schur, and they are not necessarily otherwise related! :)

I can't quite guess what your colleague had in mind, but it *is* true that in many fortuitous circumstances relevant operators are given as integral operators, and if the two-variable "kernel" $K(x,y)$ of such an operator is in $L^2$ of the product space $X\times X$, then it is not only "bounded" (really, *continuous*, which is more explanatory), but is a "Hilbert-Schmidt" operator, which is an easily-testable case of "compact operator". Self-adjoint operators are our best friends, because their spectral theory is as close to finite-dimensional spectral theory of self-adjoint operators as one could reasonable hope: orthogonal basis of eigenvectors.

Thus, compact topological groups (not $\mathbb R$...) turn out to have the nice property that all Hilbert-space repns decompose as direct sums of irreducibles.

Already the real line $G=\mathbb R$ does not behave this well: $L^2(G)$ does *not* decompose as a direct sum of irreducible repns of $G$. Rather, Fourier inversion shows that it is a "direct integral" of irreducibles, each generated by the (not $L^2$!!!) functions $x\to e^{i\xi x}$.

Comment: Meant to say "self adjoint COMPACT" operators on Hilbert spaces...